# I've installed python 3 and verified the version of urllib3 is up to date, but every time I try to import urllib3 it says no module named 'urllib3'

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, homebrew, urllib3

Here is the output of pip3 freeze:

```
Chases-MBP:/ chasehippen$ pip3 freeze
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
flake8==3.5.0
get==0.0.39
idna==2.6
mccabe==0.6.1
pew==1.1.2
pipenv==9.0.3
post==0.0.26
public==0.0.65
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
query-string==0.0.28
request==0.0.26
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
```

And here's what happens when I try to import requests or urllib3:

```
Chases-MBP:/ chasehippen$ python3
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
>>> import urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

I reinstalled python 3 via homebrew twice, I don't understand why it won't let me import the modules?

If I run python import urllib2, that works fine, but only urllib3 fails.

Here are the outputs of where

```
Chases-MBP:~ chasehippen$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
Chases-MBP:~ chasehippen$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `which pip3` and `which python3`?

Comment: added via edit to main post

Comment: Hm, okay, one more: what about `echo $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: That's empty... Where and how should I be setting the python path? I haven't found any good documentation for this.

Comment: Hey I figured it out. All of the resources I saw were saying I need to add the paths to .profile or .bashrc, but on mac, or at least mine, it's .bash_profile. I had to add "export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/":/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages" to that file, and now importing works like a charm. Thank you so much for leading me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

All of the resources I saw were saying I need to add the paths to .profile or .bashrc, but on mac, or at least mine, it's .bash_profile. I had to add "export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}/Library/Frameworks/Python.framewor‌​k/Versions/3.6/bin/"‌​:/usr/local/lib/pyth‌​on3.6/site-packages" to that file, and now importing works like a charm.

For anyone in the future reading this for an answer to using python3 on a mac, the file is ~/bash_profile , adding the line above in place of the default line that python 3 puts in there lets you use all of the modules that are installed in site-packages instead of bin